# Will the for loop effect the speed in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this code which splits the dataframe in 10000 rows and writes to file.

I tried instance with z1d with 24cpu and 192GB but even that didn't do much speed and for 1 million rows it took 9 mins.

This is code

```
total = df2.count()
offset = 10000
counter = int(total/offset) + 1

idxDf = df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

for i in range(0, counter):
    lower = i * offset
    upper = lower + offset
    filter = f"idx > {lower} and idx < {upper}"
    ddf = idxDf.filter(filter)
    ddf2 = ddf.drop("idx")
    ddf2.write.option("header", "false").option("delimiter", " ").option("compression","gzip").csv(outputpath)
```

Is there any way i can make in it. Currently i am using single master node only. I have 100 million rows and want to know how fast i can do that with emr.

Look like my normal python code is also able to do the same stuff in same minutes

Comment: Why are you trying to split then write the dataframe in batches of 10000?

Comment: Do explicitly *need* to write to a bunch of gzipped csv files?

Comment: @dijksterhuis Basically these are log message files which i need to enhanced with further processing. My initial thinking was to do in spark alone but with large dataset it is taking forever and i have no idea how far its done or not. I have tested that in plane python it takes 3 mins to finish 10000 records. so my plan was to split into 10k chunks and use aws Lambda to  trigger on file place in s3

Comment: can you do show dataframe, I would like to know the columns details to repartition that before write

Answer (score 3):

A few problems with what you’re trying to do here:

1. Stop trying to write pyspark code as if it’s normal python code. It isn’t. Read up on exactly how spark works first and foremost. You’ll have more success if you change the way you program when you use spark, not try to get spark to do what you want in the way you want.
2. Avoid `for` loops with Spark wherever possible. `for` loops only work within native python, so you’re not utilising spark when you start one. Which means one CPU on one Spark node will run the code.
3. Python is, by default, single threaded. Adding more CPUs will do literally nothing to performance for native python code (ie your `for` loop) unless you rewrite your code for either (a) multi-threaded processing (b) distributed processing (ie spark).
4. You only have one master node (and I assume zero slaves nodes). That’s going to take *aaaaaaggggggggeeeessss* to process a 192GB file. The point of Spark is to distribute the workload onto many other slave nodes. There’s some really technical ways to determine the optimal number of slave nodes for your problem. Try something like >50 or >100 or slaves. Should help you see a decent performance uplift (each node able to process at least between 1gb-4gb of data). Still too slow? Either add more slave nodes, or choose more powerful machines for the slaves. I remember running a 100GB file through some heavy lifting took a whole day on 16 nodes. Upping the machine spec and number of slaves brought it down to an hour.

For writing files, don’t try and reinvent the wheel if you don’t need to.

Spark will automatically write your files in a distributed manner according to the level of partitioning on the dataframe. On disk, it should create a directory called `outputpath` which contains the n distributed files:

```
df.repartition(n_files)
df.write.option("header", "false").option("delimiter", " ").option("compression","gzip").csv(outputpath)
```

You should get a directory structured something like this:

```
path/to/outputpath:
- part-737hdeu-74dhdhe-uru24.csv.gz
- part-24hejje—hrhehei-47dhe.csv.gz
- ...
```

Hope this helps. Also, partitioning is super important. If your initial file is not distributed (one big csv), it’s a good idea to do `df.repartition(x)` on the resulting dataframe after you load it, where `x = number of slave nodes`.

Comment: Thanks man , that was very insightful . so far i have not find any examples where i can see how people have done distributed processing using pyspark python. I tried to use it but then wroker runs forever is there any way to track how many records is being processed so that i can see the progess. I have function which does processing and i use map on dataset. I have found that normal python code runs faster that pyspark